# shell script invoked from multiple threads at same time

Tags: java, shell, jakarta-ee, unix, aix

I am invoking a aix shell script from java with Runtime.exec method.
The shell script takes a file name as input.
Based on the file name the operation inside the script is written.The output of the shell depends on the input parameter.

If multiple java threads are invoking the shell script parallely at the same time ,will it create a problem? (Each java thread may call the script with different file name.)
Do I have to write a separate shell script for each parallel execution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the shell script itself can run in parallel without disturbing the other invocations, this will not create a problem.

For each invocation of the script a separate process (on aix level) is spawned.

Comment: The main script internally calls other shell scripts also.will this also be working fine if the main script is called by different parallel threads?

Comment: This really depends on the shell scripts and has nothing to do with them being started from Java. If they use the same resources (for example one removes a directory another one tries to write to) there will be conflicts.